# Problema asíncrono usando API Fetch

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando con la API Fetch simulando hacer una petición a una database para renderizar unas tarjetas con contenido que me da la respuesta. Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando ejecuto una funcion aparte (llamada searchFilter()) para filtrar las tarjetas segun lo que escriba el usuario en un input (simulando ser un buscador) no me funciona. Este es el código:

1. Trayendome los datos con Fetch y renderizando las tarjetas:

```
function renderCards(sectionID, templateID){

    let section = d.getElementById(sectionID),
    template = d.getElementById(templateID).content,
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    fetch('js/db.json')
    .then((res)=>{return res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res);})
    
    .then((json)=>{

        json.forEach((movie)=>{
        
            template.querySelector('figure').setAttribute('data-id',`${movie.id}`);
            template.querySelector('figure').setAttribute('data-title',`${movie.title}`);
            template.querySelector('figure').setAttribute('data-description',`${movie.description}`);

            template.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src',`${movie.poster}`);

            let clone = d.importNode(template, true);
            fragment.appendChild(clone);
            section.appendChild(fragment);

        })
    })

    .catch((err)=>{
        // console.log(err);
        section.innerHTML = `<h1>¡No se han podido obtener las películas! / Razón: <span style="color:yellow">${err.statusText} ${err.status}</span></h1>`
    })
}
```

2. Declarando la funcion para filtrar las tarjetas:

```
function searchFilter(inputID, cardSelector){

    let input = d.getElementById(inputID),
    cards = d.querySelectorAll(cardSelector);

    d.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{

        if(e.target === input){
            
            cards.forEach((card)=>{
                cardAttributes = [card.getAttribute('data-id'),card.getAttribute('data-title'), card.getAttribute('data-description')];
                if(cardAttributes[0].includes(input.value) || cardAttributes[1].includes(input.value)|| cardAttributes[2].includes(input.value) || input.value === ""){
                    card.classList.remove('hidden');
                }
                else{card.classList.add('hidden');}
            })
        }
    })
}
```

3. Pego las funciones al DOM y lo único que funciona es renderCards();

```
d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e)=>{
    
    renderCards('media-container', 'template-card');
    searchFilter('search-input', '.movie-card');
})
```

PD: La única solución que pude hayar fue pegar la función searchFilter() en un .finally() despues de usar la respuesta para renderizar las tarjetas, es decir, el siguiente código:

```
function renderCards(sectionID, templateID){

    let section = d.getElementById(sectionID),
    template = d.getElementById(templateID).content,
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    fetch('js/db.json')
    .then((res)=>{return res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res);})
    
    .then((json)=>{

        json.forEach((movie)=>{
        
            template.querySelector('figure').setAttribute('data-id',`${movie.id}`);
            template.querySelector('figure').setAttribute('data-title',`${movie.title}`);
            template.querySelector('figure').setAttribute('data-description',`${movie.description}`);

            template.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src',`${movie.poster}`);

            let clone = d.importNode(template, true);
            fragment.appendChild(clone);
            section.appendChild(fragment);

        })
    })

    .catch((err)=>{
        // console.log(err);
        section.innerHTML = `<h1>¡No se han podido obtener las películas! / Razón: <span style="color:yellow">${err.statusText} ${err.status}</span></h1>`
    })

    .finally(()=>{
        searchFilter('search-input', '.movie-card');
    })
}
```

Sé que tiene que ver con algo respecto a la asincronía, pero no sé que es, he estado estudiando e investigando un poco pero quiero la ayuda de alguien que sepa más que yo sobre esto, y, si es posible, una solución más "estandar" ó adecuada.

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.